# How to call a function in php for iOS passbook file download

Tags: php, ios, passbook

I have a getPass.php which creates a Pass instance.  Here is the code:

```
//create new pass instance
$coupon = new Pass("pass/source");

//fill in dynamic data
$coupon->content['serialNumber'] = (string)uniqid();
$coupon->content['coupon']['secondaryFields'][0]['value'] = 
    (string)$_POST['name'];
$coupon->content['locations'][0] = 
   $locations[(int)$_POST['location']];

$coupon->writePassJSONFile();

$coupon->writeRecursiveManifest();
$coupon->writeSignatureWithKeysPathAndPassword("pass", '12345');
$fileName = $coupon->writePassBundle();

echo "File saved to - $fileName";

**/* THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO PRESENT IT */**
$this->outputPassBundleAsWebDownload($fileName);
```

Then Pass.php does a lot of stuff, which works because Ive used it for emailing working passes but Im replacing the emailing functionality with the presentation/download functionality.  So here is the code for Pass.php:

```
<?php
class Pass {
    private $workFolder = null;
    private $ID = null;

    var $content = null;
    var $passBundleFile = null;

    private function copySourceFolderFilesToWorkFolder($path) {
      //recurse over contents and copy files
      $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                     new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
                     RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

      foreach($files as $name => $fileObject){
        if (is_file($name) && 
            substr($fileObject->getFileName(), 0, 1)!=".") {

          copy($name, 
            $this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
        } else if (is_dir($name)) {
          mkdir($this->workFolder."/".
                str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
        }
      }
    }

    //import a json file into the object
    function readPassFromJSONFile($filePath) {
      //read the json file and decode to an object
      $this->content = 
         json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath),true);
    }

    //export a json file from the object
    function writePassJSONFile() {
      file_put_contents($this->workFolder."/pass.json",
                        json_encode($this->content));
    }

    //generate the manifest file
    function writeRecursiveManifest() {
      //create empty manifest
      $manifest = new ArrayObject();

      //recurse over contents and build the manifest
      $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                 new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->workFolder), 
                 RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

      foreach($files as $name => $fileObject){
        if (is_file($name) && 
              substr($fileObject->getFileName(), 0, 1)!=".") {

          $relativeName = str_replace($this->workFolder.
                                        "/","",$name);

          $sha1 = sha1(file_get_contents(
                         $fileObject->getRealPath()
                  ));
          $manifest[$relativeName] = $sha1;
        }
      }

       //printf debug
       // print_r($manifest);

          //write the manifest file
      file_put_contents($this->workFolder."/manifest.json",
                          json_encode($manifest));
    }

    //generate the bundle signature
    function writeSignatureWithKeysPathAndPassword($keyPath, $pass) {
      $keyPath = realpath($keyPath);


          if (!file_exists($keyPath.'/WWDR.pem')) 
            die("Save the WWDR certificate as
                 $keyPath/WWDR.pem");

      if (!file_exists($keyPath.'/passcertificate.pem')) 
        die("Save the pass certificate as 
             $keyPath/passcertificate.pem");

      if (!file_exists($keyPath.'/passkey.pem')) 
        die("Save the pass certificate key as 
             $keyPath/passkey.pem");

      $output = shell_exec("openssl smime -binary -sign". " -certfile '".$keyPath."/WWDR.pem'".
             " -signer '".$keyPath."/passcertificate.pem'".
             " -inkey '".$keyPath."/passkey.pem'".
             " -in '".$this->workFolder."/manifest.json'".
             " -out '".$this->workFolder."/signature'".
             " -outform DER -passin pass:'$pass'");
    }

        //signature debugging
       //print(file_get_contents($this->workFolder."/signature"));

    //create the zip bundle from the pass files
    function writePassBundle() {  
      //1 generate the name for the .pkpass file
      $passFile = $this->workFolder."/".$this->ID.".pkpass";

      //2 create Zip class instance
      $zip = new ZipArchive();
      $success = $zip->open($passFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
      if ($success!==TRUE) die("Can't create file $passFile");

      //3 recurse over contents and build the list
      $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                 new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->workFolder), 
                 RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

      //4 add files to the archive
      foreach($files as $name => $fileObject){
        if (is_file($name) && 
            substr($fileObject->getFileName(), 0, 1)!=".") {

          $relativeName = str_replace($this->workFolder."/", 
                                      "",$name);
          $zip->addFile($fileObject->getRealPath(), $relativeName);
        }
      }

      //5 close the zip file
      $zip->close();  

      //6 save the .pkpass file path and return it too
      $this->passBundleFile = $passFile;
      return $passFile;
    }

    //make new instance from a source folder
    function __construct($path) {
      assert(file_exists($path."/pass.json"));

      $this->ID = uniqid();

      $this->workFolder = sys_get_temp_dir()."/".$this->ID;
      mkdir($this->workFolder);
      assert(file_exists($this->workFolder));

      $this->copySourceFolderFilesToWorkFolder($path);

      $this->readPassFromJSONFile($this->workFolder."/pass.json");  
    }

    //delete all auto-generated files in the temp folder
    function cleanup()
    {
      //recurse over contents and delete files
      $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                 new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->workFolder), 
                 RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

      foreach($files as $name => $fileObject){
        if (is_file($name)) {
          unlink($name);
        } else if (is_dir($name)) {
          rmdir($name);
        }
      }

      rmdir($this->workFolder);
    }

    //cleanup the temp folder on object destruction
    function __destruct() {
      $this->cleanup();
    }

        **/* THIS I ADDED AS A NEW FUNCTION TO PRESENT/DOWNLOAD */
        function outputPassBundleAsWebDownload($fileName) {
         //dump the generated pass to the browser
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; ".
         "filename=".basename($this->$fileName));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ". filesize($this->$fileName));
        flush();
        readfile($this->$fileName);**
}
}

?>
```

The thing is the pass isnt being presented.  Its being created properly because I get the echo on the screen with the fileName.  What am Im missing?  Im calling the output function from the getPass.php and passing in the $fileName.  Why isnt it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to comment out the line that echos the file name. Echoing content to the browser forces PHP to automatically generate headers for text output, so it can serve the text of your file name.

Once output to the browser has started, you cannot send additional headers.  This is why your headers in your output pass bundle function are being ignored and your pass is not being downloaded.